# How to make use of an ASP.Net MVC controller action using Ajax to return the difference between two dates in a form?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using MVC3 and have a view which is used to book leave for employees. As part of this I want to display the number of days to be taken based on two dates that they enter - I've done this in a rudimentary way using jQuery but want to make use of a controller action I've got which will return a single value based on the two dates (it takes into account weekends and bank holidays).

The question is, what is the best way to pass the values of DateFrom and DateTo (the two inputs) to the controller and retrieve the result using Ajax? I want this value to update whenever either of the dates is changed and without submitting the whole form.

I'm not sure of the best practice for this sort of thing so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The question is, what is the best way to pass the values of DateFrom and DateTo (the two inputs) to the controller and retrieve the result using Ajax?

You could subscribe to the change event of those textboxes and send an AJAX request:

```
$(function() {
    $('#DateFrom, #DateTo').change(function() {
        // whenever the user changes the value send an AJAX request:
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("SomeAction", "SomeController")',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 
            data: JSON.stringify({ 
                dateFrom: $('#DateFrom').val(), 
                dateTo: $('#DateTo').val() 
            }),
            success: function(result) {
                // TODO: The AJAX call succeeded => do something with the results
            }
        });
    });
});
```

and the controller action could look like this:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(DateTime dateFrom, DateTime dateTo)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it. May be worth doing some basic validation on the client to ensure that both date fields are valid and the start date is before the end date just to save any unnecessary server calls.

Comment: Thanks for that. I've added the function but the ajax call isn't actually doing anything. The change event is definitely firing but the breakpoint I've got in the action isn't ever reached. Is there something I might have missed? The action and controller names are definitely correct, as are the input ids.

Comment: @user703845, are the dates you are entering inside those fields valid? You may try the following format: `yyyy-MM-dd`.

Comment: The dates are in the format dd/mm/yyyy, Firebug tells me the error returned is "Illegal characters in path." - if I take out the double quotes around the action and controller names then I don't receive and error but the action still isn't called.

Comment: @user703845, yes the problem is with this format. I have updated my answer showing how you could use `JSON.stringify` along with `contentType` to send a JSON request where the format wouldn't be problematic.

Comment: Thanks for that Darin, I actually managed to get it working by using url: '/Leave/CheckDates/' to define the path - it wasn't a problem with the dates at all it seems. It's all working now though so thanks!