# MVC pass date range to controller using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Sorry if my question sounds noob, but I am a real beginner in javascript. I have 2 parameters "**startdate**" and "**enddate**". I want to pass it to controller via this javascript:

**View: (Updated)**

```
<div class="inventoryTypeList">
<p>
    <label for="start">From:</label>
        @(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
              .Name("from")
              .Events(e => e.Change("startChange"))
        )

        <label for="end">To:</label>
        @(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
              .Name("to")
              .Events(e => e.Change("endChange"))
        )
</p>
    <button class="k-button" id="showGrid">Search</button>
</div>

<script>

    function startChange() {
        var endPicker = $("#to").data("kendoDatePicker"),
            startDate = this.value();

        if (startDate) {
            startDate = new Date(startDate);
            startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 1);
            endPicker.min(startDate);
        }
    }

    function endChange() {
        var startPicker = $("#from").data("kendoDatePicker"),
            endDate = this.value();

        if (endDate) {
            endDate = new Date(endDate);
            endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() - 1);
            startPicker.max(endDate);
        }
    }

    $(function () {

        $("#showGrid").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("PastTransactionsPartial", "InventoryTransactions")',
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                cache: false,
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    dateFrom: $('#from').val(),
                    dateTo: $('#to').val(),
                }),
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#divPastTransactions').replaceWith(result);
                },
                error: function () { alert("Please specify from and to dates"); }
            });
        });
    });

</script>

<div id="divPastTransactions"  ></div>
```

**Controller: (Updated)**

```
public ActionResult PastTransactionsPartial(DateTime dateFrom, DateTime dateTo)
    {
        var inventorytransactions = db.InventoryTransactions.Include(i => i.InventoryTransactionType).Include(i => i.InventoryType).Include(i => i.Supplier).Where(i => i.InventoryTransactionDate >= dateFrom && i.InventoryTransactionDate <= dateTo);
        return PartialView("_PastTransactionsPartial", inventorytransactions.ToList());
    }
```

How do I do that? and what do I capture them in the controller?

The results will be displayed in partial view underneath the search function

*Edit:
closing this thread and put the issue into new thread*

Comment: You will need to pass them using AJAX and n POST action method.

Comment: You said: "I have 2 parameters".  Where are they?

Comment: @DavidTansey it is the startdate and enddate

Comment: @SachinKainth I am loading a grid using partial view afterwards. Sorry I forgot to include that

Comment: As @SachinKainth indicated you will need to use POST instead of GET when you call the controller, and your controller action is going to need a couple of `DateTime` parameters.

Comment: @DavidTansey do you mean to add [HttpPost] to the controller?

Comment: Take a look at the following post which has some code examples that are quite close to what you wish to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634014/how-to-make-use-of-an-asp-net-mvc-controller-action-using-ajax-to-return-the-dif

Comment: @DavidTansey when I changed the `$.get` function to `var url = '@Url.Action("PastTransactionsPartial", "InventoryTransactions")';
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (result) {
                $('#divPastTransactions').replaceWith(data);
            },
            error: function () { alert('something bad happened'); }
        });`, the grid won't show up. :(

Comment: didn't expect that this is going to be that hard :s

Comment: You're getting closer.  I don't see you passing any parameters in your ajax call (like in the sample I posted)!

Comment: @DavidTansey I managed to pull it through until it is showing the result. But now I have a new problem, the grid won't showing new result if I put new values and click Search. any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View:

```
<div class="searchPastTransactions">
<p>
    <label for="start">From:</label>
        @(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
              .Name("from")
              .Events(e => e.Change("startChange"))
        )

        <label for="end">To:</label>
        @(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
              .Name("to")
              .Events(e => e.Change("endChange"))
        )
</p>
    <button class="k-button" id="showGrid">Search</button>
</div>

<script>

    function startChange() {
        var endPicker = $("#to").data("kendoDatePicker"),
            startDate = this.value();

        if (startDate) {
            startDate = new Date(startDate);
            startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 1);
            endPicker.min(startDate);
        }
    }

    function endChange() {
        var startPicker = $("#from").data("kendoDatePicker"),
            endDate = this.value();

        if (endDate) {
            endDate = new Date(endDate);
            endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() - 1);
            startPicker.max(endDate);
        }
    }

    $(function () {

        $("#showGrid").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("PastTransactionsPartial", "InventoryTransactions")',
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                cache: false,
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    dateFrom: $('#from').val(),
                    dateTo: $('#to').val(),
                }),
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#divPastTransactions').replaceWith(result);
                },
                error: function () { alert("Please specify from and to dates"); }
            });
        });
    });

</script>

<div id="divPastTransactions"  ></div>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult PastTransactionsPartial(DateTime dateFrom, DateTime dateTo)
        {
            var inventorytransactions = db.InventoryTransactions.Include(i => i.InventoryTransactionType).Include(i => i.InventoryType).Include(i => i.Supplier).Where(i => i.InventoryTransactionDate >= dateFrom && i.InventoryTransactionDate <= dateTo);
            return PartialView("_PastTransactionsPartial", inventorytransactions.ToList());
        }
```